# Default values for properties in Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure

I am using Azure table storage and have questions about how nulls and default values for entities work.

Specifically, I have a class that extends `TableServiceEntity`.  The default constructor for this class is setting default values for various properties like so:

```
public class MyEntity: TableServiceEntry
{
    public MyEntity() : MyEntity("invalid", "invalid") {}
    public MyEntity(string f1, string f2) 
    {
        Field1 = f1;
        Field2 = f2;
    }

    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
 }
```

I tested this class locally (on the emulator) by constructing the following entity:

```
MyEntity e = new MyEntity("hello", null);
```

I uploaded the entity and then retrieved it locally and the two fields were set to "hello" and null, respectively, as expected.

However, when I uploaded the same entity to the Azure cloud, what I received back was "hello" and "invalid", respectively, for the two properties.

My code that saves the entity is below:

```
public class MyTable : TableServiceContext
{
    ...
    public void AddEntry(MyEntity e)
    {
        this.AddObject("MyTable", e);
        this.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);
    }
}
```

I was able to fix this by making the default constructor take no arguments, but now I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how table storage works.  Is it true that when you specify defaults for properties of a TableServiceEntry, those become the defaults for each row in the table in the cloud but not in the emulator (i.e. cloud vs. SQL Express)?  If so, why can't I override those defaults with `null` in the cloud?  Is there any documentation that explains how default constructors and `null`s work in Azure table storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between how table storage behaves in the emulator and in the cloud. The emulator implemented in SQL server, returns all columns defined for a table, even if not defined for a row, irrespective of the columns value (null / non-null). In the cloud, a property set to null is neither stored nor returned in the REST call.

A quick fix would be to check for null in property set, and only mutate the property if the value passed in, is not null.

Comment: Just to explain a different way, what's happening is that the null isn't being stored. On retrieval, the class is initializing itself to have the value "invalid," and then the storage library overwrites fields with the values that came back from storage. Because there's no value for Field2 (not even a null), Field2 is not touched and still contains "invalid."

Comment: The behavior I observed is exactly how @smarx and @Lucifure describe.  There appear to be two major take aways.  (1) `null` is not stored/returned. (2) The flow of control when retrieving an entity is from an Azure table is that the default constructor is called and then any (existing) values in the table are populated.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Devstorage and real storage behave differently in some cases, but I've never seen them handle NULL values differently. And I've certainly never seen it change a value from NULL to "invalid", as you seem to be implying. Are you sure you didn't accidentally upload the wrong values to the cloud? You may want to try again, and use Fiddler to look at the actual request and response values.